Selecting multiple sections within polygon to create multiple separate polygons in QGIS
I have a large polygon split up into many different sections. Each section has an ID number ranging from 1-13. I want to be able to select all polygons with a certain ID, and then create a separate vector polygon with just that ID number.
Eg - I want to select all the sections of the polygon with the value of 7, and then cut them out and create another polygon of just that.

Its in QGIS; forgot to mention it in the post, sorry.

What do you mean by sections? From your question it sounds like they are simply their own individual polygons. Is that correct?

Are you looking for Extract By Expression?
